# django left join + group by count(*), includes zero counts

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

```
class ItemGroup(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Item(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   group = models.ForeignKey(ItemGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to display all the item groups, and for each group show the number of items the group has, and include groups which have no items.

In SQL I use left join for this purpose:

```
SELECT item_group.name, COUNT(*) as item_count
FROM item_group
LEFT JOIN item ON item_group.id = item.id
GROUP BY item_group.id, item_group.name
```

So I get groups with zero counts as well.

How to do the equivalent query with django ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use django **annotations**. Modify your foreign key slightly to:

```
group = models.ForeignKey(ItemGroup, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

for convenient naming.

Then run `python manage.py makemigration` followed by
`python manage.py migrate`

Then it's time to annotate.

```
from django.db.models import Count
ItemGroup.objects.annotate(no_of_items=Count('items'))
```

What this does is add to each `ItemGroup` object an attribute called `no_of_items` which is a count of the `items` related to it.

Now if you do `item_group = ItemGroup.objects.get(id=1)` assuming item group 1 had 3 items related to it you can do `item_group.no_of_items` which would give you 3. If another ItemGroup had 0 items it would return zero.

For more on annotations see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/